# How do I avoid type errors when internal function returns 'Union' that could be 'None'?

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting, python-typing

I've been running into a bit of weirdness with Unions (and Optionals, of course) in Python - namely it seems that the static type checker tests properties against all member of a union, and not a member of the union (i.e. it seems overly strict?). As an example, consider the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   df = df.fillna(df)
   return df
```

This creates a type warning, as `pd.fillna(..., inplace: Bool = False, ...) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]` (it is a `None` return if `inplace=True`). I suspect that in theory the static type checker should realize the return of the function changes depending on the arguments (as that should be known when code is written), but that's a bit beyond the point.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the best way to resolve this? I can think of two solutions:

   i) do nothing -- which creates ugly squiggles in my code

   ii) `cast` the return of `fillna` to a `pd.DataFrame`; my understanding is this is a informative  step to the static type checker so should not cause any concerns or issues?
2. Let us consider that I'm writing a function `f` which, similarly to this, has its return types vary depending on the function call inputs, and this should be determinable before runtime. In order to avoid such errors in the future; what is the best way to go about writing this function? Would it be better to do something like a `@typing.overload`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying function should really be defined as an overload -- I'd suggest a patch to pandas probably

Here's what the type [looks like right now](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/20b4c29e4bc5848b9687814c2242b4eb10306fa6/pandas/core/generic.py#L6234-L6243):

```py
    def fillna(
        self: FrameOrSeries,
        value=None,
        method=None,
        axis=None,
        inplace: bool_t = False,
        limit=None,
        downcast=None,
    ) -> Optional[FrameOrSeries]: ...
```

in reality, a better way to represent this is to use an `@overload` -- the function returns `None` when `inplace = True`:

```py
    @overload
    def fillna(
        self: FrameOrSeries,
        value=None,
        method=None,
        axis=None,
        inplace: Literal[True] = False,
        limit=None,
        downcast=None,
    ) -> None: ...


    @overload
    def fillna(
        self: FrameOrSeries,
        value=None,
        method=None,
        axis=None,
        inplace: Literal[False] = False,
        limit=None,
        downcast=None,
    ) -> FrameOrSeries: ...


    def fillna(
        self: FrameOrSeries,
        value=None,
        method=None,
        axis=None,
        inplace: bool_t = False,
        limit=None,
        downcast=None,
    ) -> Optional[FrameOrSeries]:
        # actual implementation
```

---

but assuming you can't change the underlying library you have several approaches to unpacking the union.  I made [a video about this](https://youtu.be/yH6L3UiK9WM) specifically for `re.match` but I'll reiterate here since it's basically the same problem (`Optional[T]`)

#### option 1: an assert indicating the expected return type

the assert tells the type checker something it doesn't know: that the type is narrower than it knows about.  mypy will trust this assertion and the type will be assumed to be `pd.DataFrame`

```py
def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   ret = df.fillna(df)
   assert ret is not None
   return ret
```

#### option 2: cast

explicitly tell the type checker that the type is what you expect, "cast"ing away the `None`-ness

```py
from typing import cast

def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   ret = cast(pd.DataFrame, df.fillna(df))
   return ret
```

#### type: ignore

the (imo) hacky solution is to tell the type checker to ignore the incompatibility, I would not suggest this approach but it can be helpful as a quick fix

```py
def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   ret = df.fillna(df)
   return ret  # type: ignore
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method is defined as returning either `DataFrame` or `None`.

If there is a possibility that a function will return `None`, then this should be documented by using an `Optional` type hint. It would be wrong to try to hide the fact a function could return `None` by using a cast or a comment to ignore the warning such as:

```
return df  # type: ignore
```

## If function could return `None`, use `Optional`

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional


def test_dummy() -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
    df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0])
    df = df.fillna(value=0)
    return df
```

## Function guaranteed not to return `None`, there are these options

If you can guarantee that a function will not return `None`, but it cannot be statically inferred by a type checker, then there are three options.

#### Option 1: Use an assertion to indicate that DataFrame is not None

This is the approach recommended by the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#unexpected-errors-about-none-and-or-optional-types).

```python
def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0])
    df = df.fillna(value=0)
    assert df is not None 
    return df
```

#### Option 2: Use a cast

```python
from typing import cast

def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0])
    df = cast(pd.DataFrame, df.fillna(value=0))
    return df
```

#### Option 3: Tell mypy to ignore the warning (not recommended)

```python
from typing import cast

def test_dummy() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0])
    df = df.fillna(value=0)
    return df  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, but I'm not sure it addresses the issue I'm looking at. I'm aware of why MyPy creates a type error on the use of `fillna`; it's because the return type of `fillna` is `Optional[pd.DataFrame]`. MyPy checks the use of variable returned against both types (`pd.DataFrame` and `None`) for the rest of the code, so the error actually occurs at the `return` of the `test_dummy` function, not at `fillna` -- it can't match the `-> pd.DataFrame` of `test_dummy` with the `-> Optional[pd.DataFrame]` of `fillna`.

Comment: I think this is a generic problem with `Unions` that don't share attributes, and think the question as originally asked targets that.

Comment: D'oh. I'm an idiot, and that was a typo in my hypothetical example; I'm so sorry. The example was supposed to be df.fillna. Yes, that creates a type warning, and that's what I meant to ask about. I don't even think there is a pandas.fillna function!

Comment: @deetsb See updated answer showing the use of `Optional`, or alternatively, using an assertion to tell mypy that the DataFrame will definitely not be `None`.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! If I'm correct, Option 1 will actually still propagate the typing error; it just delays it down the chain. As an example, if you do (using your definition of `test_dummy`) 'df_1 = test_dummy()', and follow that up with 'df_1=df_1.fillna()', it'll throwing a typing error (Item `None` of 'Optional[Any]` has no attribute groupby).

Your `assert` solution is cool; I hadn't thought about that! It's pretty similar to using `cast` (although perhaps safer); I was just wondering if there were a way to tell MyPy that this is deterministic without just overruling it.

Comment: @deetsb If you type the function's return type as `Optional`, then yes, it propagates the possibility that the function could return `None`. However, mypy also recognizes checks such as `if df is not None:`, and within that `if` block, there would be no type error accessing `DataFrame` methods.